# Centring 2 images on one line

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

What is the best way to display two pictures on a one line such that together they will be centred ? This is what I tried so far but it displays images very far from each other

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]

\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 1.25in]{loss_test}
\end{center}
  \caption{Test loss}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 1.25in]{accuracy_test}
  \caption{Test accuracy}
\endminipage

\end{figure}
```

Comment: what do you mean by centred? a fixed space between them and centre that block as a single item,. or have three equal stretched spaces so `space,image,space,image,space` or ...

Comment: Welcome! A picture is just like a big character, so the same method for centering a word will work.

Comment: Never ever use `\minipage` and `\endminipage` in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (as mentioned David Carlisle in his comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 1.25in]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Test loss}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 1.25in]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Test loss}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]